# Unable To Get Postcode/Zip Code From Geocoder - Returns Null

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, google-geocoder

I am trying to get the postcode / zip code using geocoder

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() == 1) {
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        addressString = addressString + address.getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    }
                    Log.e("TAG", "PostCode: " + address.getPostalCode());
```

`addressString` is upadated with the address - for example "12 Road Name, Town, Area, First 3 Characters of Postcode

However I want to get the `PostCode` characters separately so that I can use them elsewhere but `address.getPostalCode()` returns `null` value.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise that this does return the post code but not always, as it may not be available.

```
address.getPostalCode();
```

Thanks.